# How to format the date field when making a POST request to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am adding a series of data to my rails application through a POST request to the API.

All is working well, however, whenever I try and add data to a date field, I get the following error:

```
> undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is an example of my JSON payload:

```
{
    "product": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "start_date": "2015-11-05 22:32:03"
    }
}
```

I know there is a potential bug with this relating to Ruby 2.2 .. however when I looked at the backend for how the params were stored on a normal create action through the frontend, they were stored a lot differently:

```
"start_date(1i)"=>"2020", "start_date(2i)"=>"1", "start_date(3i)"=>"1", "start_date(4i)"=>"00", "start_date(5i)"=>"01"
```

How would I recreate this?

Comment: we'd need to see the code that is handling that date field, because that format is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: it seems backend expects to receive start date splitted by the pieces. Did you try to send data in this format? I mean following: `{"product":{"name": "Foo", "start_date(1i)": 2015, "start_date(2i)": 11,"start_date(3i)": 5, ...}}`

Comment: Hey @andrykonchin this was exactly what I did as a workaround.. feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the backend expects to receive start date splitted by the pieces.

Please try to send data in following:

```
{"product":{"name": "Foo", "start_date(1i)": 2015, "start_date(2i)": 11,"start_date(3i)": 5, ...}}
```